# Alternative to Cane Creek 200TT Brake Levers

Tags: single-speed, brake-levers

I'm newbie.

Looking for silver TT levers (not aero) for bullhorn on single speed (caliper brakes).

I'd like all silver levers (without tblack parts).

There's Cane Creek 200TT. But it has black parts nad I don't sure I like the shape.

Is there other alternatives? Something by Tektro, Die-Compe?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry we consider shopping / product recommendation questions to be off-topic.  There should be plenty of choices in cross levers in silver, try your LBS or your favourite online reseller.  Last resort is to shotblast black ones and paint them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other options out there, just one i came across are these Origin 8's that are 99% silver, they have black endcaps but wouldn't break the bank.
Tektro's version below them.
[image]

[image]

Soma Urban Pursuits are pretty sweet:

[image]
(source: [singlespeedshop.com](https://www.singlespeedshop.com/images/product_images/popup_images/soma_urbpursuitbar_all.jpg))

Comment: Soma Urban Pursuits looks lively, but pricely